how to specific the exiftool.exe path in Pycharm when running exiftool.exitToolHelper()?
When I run my Pycharm Project main.py and use the code
import exiftool
with exiftool.exitToolHelper() as et:
    metadata = et.get_metadata(file_path)[0]

the line exiftool.exitToolHelper() will have error and say that the exe cannot be found.
I need to put the exe files to the project folder to run the code

The import exiftool is loading the PyExiftool wrapper for exiftool.
If exiftool isn't installed, then you need to install it. See Installing ExifTool.
If exiftool is not in the default PATH, you need to tell PyExiftool where it is. This doc page indicates that you would use
ExifTool(executable=<full path>)
There are more details options and instructions on the Class exiftool.ExifTool page.
